Eclipse auto format: C indentation setting of #define as function call parameter
when using the Eclipse auto format feature in C function calls the identation is messed up for me when I'm using a #define as function parameter. On the first hit of the auto format everything looks fine and readable. On the second run of the auto fromat the identation is messed up when using #define as a function parameter (see pictures). Somebody have an idea on how to fix this (settings ?).
Thank you
Pictures
first run of auto format
second run of auto format
I already looked through the the setting but unfortunately I don't know how the #define is called within the settings
#define DTYPES_SPECIAL_QBIT_FAIL false
auto format settings
